# UWP C# asynchronous Socket Server can't accept

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

My Socket Server can't receive any connection requests.

Tried to connect to the server with simple Socket Service => A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:1337. 
Enabled private internet and internet (client and server) in appxmanifest.

Service:

```
IPEndPoint serviceEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1337);
Socket _serviceSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_serviceSocket.Bind(serviceEndPoint);
_serviceSocket.Listen(254);
Socket clientSocket = null;
await _serviceSocket.AcceptAsync(clientSocket);
```

Client:

```
IPAddress _address = IPAddress.Loopback;
IPEndPoint _ep = = new IPEndPoint(_address, 1337);
Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_clientSocket.Connect(_ep);
```

Comment: That certainly looks like it should work - and it works on regular .NET (non-UWP)...

Comment: And could you tell me pls why it doesn't work in UWP?

Comment: I genuinely wish I could; your code isn't crazy, though - whatever it is: it is subtle and UWP-specific :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to debug it on my Raspberry Pi and it worked. I don't know why this code doesn't work on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets), two UWP apps cannot communicate on the local host due to (what they call) network isolation. I have no experience with that but the documentation may show some configuration changes needed...